# pic 12f675 measure supply vdd with ADIN

Tags: pic, analog

have been googling and experimenting all night, could not make it works.

need to monitor pic 12f675 supply VDD, i managed to read a value as 4.2 volts,
but if the vdd voltage change it still reading same 4.2 volts!
the supply comes from LI-ion battery. connecting wires were made directly without any external components.

voltage reference is through VDD

```
ADCON0 = %10001101 ' A/D Converter ON
ANSEL = %00110010 ' Set Analog register 3
Adin_Res    10                  ' Set the resolution to 10
Adin_Tad    FRC                 ' Choose the RC osc for ADC samples
Adin_Stime  100                 ' Allow 100us for charge time

Dim Raw         As Word
Dim Value       As Word
Dim Volts       As Byte
Dim Millivolts  As Word

 INTCON = 0
 Output GPIO.2           'led
 Input GPIO.4            'adin
 Output GPIO.5           'serial

 While 1=1
      Raw = ADIn 3
      Value = 835 *(Raw / 10)           ' Quantasize the result
        Volts = Value / 10000
        Millivolts = (Value // 10000) / 100<
      SerOut GPIO.5, 84, [" ",Dec1 Volts, ".",Dec2 Millivolts]     ' Display the RAW data
      SerOut GPIO.5, 84, ["-",#Raw]     ' Display the RAW data
    High GPIO.2
    DelayMS 500
    Low GPIO.2
    DelayMS 500
 Wend
```

[image]

any advise?

Comment: How do you measure that voltage? What voltage reference are you using? Show us schematic.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that you are not using external voltage reference.
You are using Vdd as voltage reference, which is wrong, because it changes in time since it is a battery.

You are using analog input, and internal ADC. ADC gives you result relative to Vref (which is Vdd in your case). You will ALLWAYS get the same binary value, no matter what Vdd is.

You have to use either battery gauge IC, or use voltage reference (say 1.024V), use it as Vref for internal ADC. And then make voltage divider for battery voltage say 1:5 (so it will be lower that 1.024V all the time) and measure this voltage.

Or you can use 3.3V LDO voltage regulator, PIC will be powered by stable 3.3V. So Vdd will be stable. Then you will use voltage divider from batetry say 1:2 and measure this voltage.

**UPDATE:**
PIC12F675 actually has internal voltage reference. You can use it, you have to enable it. Those internal references are not very precise, prepare for that.

**UPDATE2:**
It seems that ADC cannot use internal voltage reference in this PIC.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for feedback, seems i'd been doing it in a very primitive way. i have to use 12f675, i check it does not have internal voltage reference, is this correct?

Comment: wow, you have literally light a path for me, thanks, i like the LDO, will try it now and let you know.

Comment: The reference in the  PIC12F675 is only available for use by the comparator module, not the ADC - so the OP will have to use one of your other suggested options.

Comment: @brhans, you are right. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The standard trick is to have an (internal or external) voltage reference (for a voltage lower than your power), and measure that voltage, using the Vcc (battery) as reference. From that result, you can calculate back to the battery voltage.

If you are worried that the external reference would use too much current, you can use an extra GPIO pin to power it, and switch it off between measurements.

An LM431 is a 'yellybean' component for this purpose.